# What if a value constructor should also be a type?

Tags: haskell

I am in case that a value constructor of a data type should be also a type, e.g if I have:

```
data Person = Student {name :: String, age :: Int}
            | Staff {name :: String, salary :: Float} deriving (Show)
```

I misused like this way:

```
type St = Student
```

or 
anywhere that use Student as type, e.g `[Student]` is wrong too

I know I can't do this, because `Student` is not a type! Then how to make the value constructor `Student` can be used as a type? Is it out of law?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you looking for it to be a type distinct from `Person`, or a type synonym for `Person`, or what?

Comment: Why not write 'data Person = Person..' and 'type Student = Person' ?

Comment: I just want the `Student` can be used as a kind of type. but it is still a kind of `Person`.

Comment: @Jakob Runge My bad example. What if `Student` is just one of the value constructors of a `Person`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want `Student` to be a type distinct from `Person` and `Staff`?  Make them different types, then.

```
data Person = StudentPerson Student
            | StaffPerson Staff
              deriving (Show)

data Student = Student {name :: String, age :: Int} deriving (Show)
data Staff = Staff {name :: String, salary :: Float} deriving (Show)
```

They're different types now.  You can control what it is you want.  And you don't accidentally generate partial functions like `age` and `salary` are in your case, either.

Comment: This extra level (`StudentPerson`) does help huh, though adding a little more typings.